# Auth Middleware on a button : laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a button when pressed pop out a form modal. I have 2 things i need to do:

Apply Auth Middleware on the button so that clicking the button redirects to the sign in page

Save the URL before Authentication so that you store return it after loggin in.

I have an idea on how to do '2'.

'1' is what i need the most help in

Comment: Is the button a simple link or a form?

Comment: The button launches a form (Modal)

Comment: Im assuming that the page and the modal have the same route?

Comment: The page is a result set of employees with a 'Hire' button and the page has a different route to the form modal that pop out when you click the 'hire' button

Comment: Check my answer below.